# GROUP BY (MySQL vs SQL server)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

I am having some issues with the GROUP BY clause. I was originally taught SQL in MySQL and i have recently transferred over to SQL server. However, i am really struggling with the GROUP BY clause.

I am used to being able to create queries such as:

```
    SELECT Name,Team,Date, SUM(Figure) 
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Name
```

This would give me a result such as:

```
    Name      Team     Date    Figure
    Ben        2       16/09     30
   Simon       4       16/09     55
```

But when i code the same thing in SQL server i have to GROUP BY all columns in my select clause otherwise it errors which gives me

```
    SELECT Name,Team,Date, SUM(Figure) 
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Name,Team,Date
```

And result:

```
    Name      Team     Date    Figure
    Ben        2       16/09     10
    Ben        2       19/09     20
   Simon       4       16/09     35
   Simon       4       20/09     20
```

This is because it is grouping by name,team and date.

I am looking to get a result like i had in MySQL in SQL server but this doesn't seem possible. Does anyone have any advice for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Your MySQL query shouldn't have run.  It just doesn't make sense.  How does MySQL decide to pick Date 16/09 instead of 19/09 for Ben?

Comment: MySQL will only complain about that in strict mode, but yes the first query is wrong.

Comment: In any other dbms, except MySQL, your first query will fail because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand it doesnt make sense and why but MySQL used to let that query run

Comment: @RyanGadsdon It's a good habit to write a proper query.  Simon's answer below may be what you want.

Comment: I understand the logic makes more sense in sql server but just wondered why this was allowed in MySQL

Comment: @RyanGadsdon To merge data for a given column without specifically grouping it (like `date` in your case), then you need to tell SQL *how* to merge it. As seen in your `figure` column, SQL knows how it should combine the `Figure` for each group because you've used an *aggregate query* - You've said *"for each group, `SUM` this column"*. For dates, you can use `MIN(Date)` for the earliest or `MAX(Date)` for the largest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server when you use `GROUP BY` all other columns involved will need to be aggregated properly. To achieve your results you need:

```
    SELECT Name,Team,MIN(Date), SUM(Figure) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name,Team
```

If you want the greater date you use `MAX` instead of `MIN`. I am not familiar with MySQL but your results shouldn't be possible without proper aggregation. Because how will MySql know which date to choose of the two and if there were different `Teams` for an individual, how will it know which to choose?

Answer (score 5):

This query:

```
SELECT Name, Team, Date, SUM(Figure) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
```

doesn't make sense.  What values are used for `Team` and for `Date`?

MySQL is starting to encourage ANSI compliant behavior using the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)).  The MySQL documentation even counsels against the style of query you are using:

> Disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` [which would allow your query] is useful **primarily when you know that,
>   due to some property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated
>   column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group**.

In ANSI standard SQL and in almost any other database, you need aggregation functions around all the non-aggregated columns/expressions.  Something like:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Team) as team, MAX(Date) as last_date, SUM(Figure) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name;
```

It is sad that you learned bad habits and non-portable syntax when you learned MySQL.