# GroupBy (MS SQL Server vs MySQL)

Tags: sql, group-by, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a similar issue as this person:
[GROUP BY (MySQL vs SQL server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473852/group-by-mysql-vs-sql-server)

```
SELECT 
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress,
    MIN(CreatedDate) AS CreateDate,
FROM [_ListSubscribers]
WHERE EmailAddress = 'email@address.com'
AND STATUS = 'active'
GROUP BY EmailAddress
```

How do I see what the **SubscriberKey** is that is tied to the email address with the oldest record?  The **SubscriberKey** is a TEXT field.  I tried using MIN(SubscriberKey) but it doesn't return the correct value. And adding it in the GroupBy Clause also fails to return the correct value.

This is the result I want:

| SubscriberKey | EmailAddress | CreateDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email@address.com | email@address.com | August 21, 2018 |

This is the full DB example for this email record:

| SubscriberKey | EmailAddress | CreateDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email@address.com | email@address.com | August 21, 2018 | active |
| Jadfsok134324 | email@address.com | May 15, 2020 | active |

Comment: Your query is invalid and expected to raise an exception. Will do so also in newer MySQL versions - unless in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both databases you would use a correlated subquery or `row_number()`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emailaddress ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [_ListSubscribers] l
      WHERE EmailAddress = 'email@address.com' AND STATUS = 'active'
     ) l
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Of course, if you want only one row, then `fetch first` is easier in either database:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM [_ListSubscribers] l
WHERE EmailAddress = 'email@address.com' AND STATUS = 'active'
ORDER BY createdAt ASC
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: This was VERY helpful.  What if I want to get all records and only return by unique email?

My end goal is to find all unique emails in a database and return the ones with the oldest createdate.  Then I can use that as a subquery to delete all other records as those are duplicates.

Comment: @Martin . . . You would remove the `where` clause.  That is in your logic.  I didn't add it.